# How to extend instantiated class method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to extend a class method that comes from a compiled DLL, and am trying to do this from inside of an MVC project. However, for some reason, it does not pick this up.

This is how i usually extend an instantiated class method, as an example:

```
    public static string CSVEncode(this string original)
    {
        //.......
    }
```

With this, if i have any string, i can see and call the `CSVEncode()` method from the object itself, like this as an example:

```
string temp = "some string goes here";
string csv = temp.CSVEncode();
```

However, in this latest attempt it simply does not work...

Here's a small definition of the object I am trying to extend for this question's purposes (e.g.: there are more properties and methods that don't need to be iterated here).

```
namespace SomeOtherDLL.HumanRace
{
    public class Human
    {
       //... some properties... 

       public Human(){ }

       public bool CanAccess(string AppName)
       {
         //....  
       }
    }
}
```

In my MVC solution, i have a Common project which includes a class called `Extensions`. In this class is where i put all my extensions, including the one I am trying to perform for the object above.

However, this does NOT show up in Intellisense anywhere afterwards, and if i try to build or compile, i get an error saying that this method does not exist, and i simply do not understand why?

```
namespace MyProj.Common
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static bool CanAccess(this HumanRace.Human original, int AppID)
        {
            //...some code here... 
        }
    }
}
```

Now from what i can tell of the other object extensions i've done in the past, this should work perfectly...

Here's an example of how i try to use it in a View page:

```
@model SomeOtherDLL.HumanRace.Human
@using MyProj.Common.Extensions

@Html.Raw(Model.CanAccess(59) ? "<img src='CanAccess.jpg' />" : "<img src='CannotAccess.jpg' />")

.............
```

This does not resolve in Visual Studio... am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Extensions class is in the namespace MyProj.Common, but you don't seem to be including that in your view.  Try adding

```
@using MyProj.Common
```

to your view.

Comment: + the model is most likely SomeOtherDLL.HumanRace.Human for SomeOtherDLL.HumanRace is a namespace and not a type

Comment: you are both correct in that my question should reflect this, however, i do have those properly set in my view... see corrections above as they reflect  EXACTLY how my code is setup in the view... my bad for now typing those in correctly.

Comment: this actually solved it. Using the namespace instead of the static class solved all my woes! Thank you so much! ** You can accept an answer in 7 minutes** -- will do!

Comment: Yes you cannot include the class name in the using statement.

Comment: Or if you're using C# 6 and have `using static` :-)